# Prove that $r^3\rho=2R \rho_1\rho_2 \rho_3$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Let $ABC $ be an acute-angled triangle.
Let $D$, $E$, $F$ be the feet of the perpendiculars from $A $, $B$, $C $ on the opposite sides $BC $, $CA $, $AB $. Let $\rho,\rho_1,\rho_2 ,\rho_3$ be the radii of the circles inscribed in the triangles $DEF$, $AEF$, $BFD$, $CDE$.

Prove that $r^3\rho=2R \rho_1\rho_2 \rho_3$.

Here, $r $ is the radius of the incircle of triangle $ABC$, and $R$ is the circumradius of $ ABC$.

Comment: you can cancel $\rho$ from both sides, and what are r and R?

Comment: r is radius of incircle of ABC and R is circumradius of ABC.

Comment: do you have any references for it?

Comment: I think that the relation you want is $$r^3 \rho = 2 R \rho_1 \rho_2 \rho_3$$ (You have an extra $\rho$ on the right-hand side.) I have a GeoGebra sketch that suggests that this relation holds.

Comment: @Blue,Sir how will we prove it?Any hints.

Comment: @diya: Start by noticing that $\triangle AEF$, $\triangle BFD$, $\triangle CDE$ are all conveniently similar to $\triangle ABC$, giving a nice relation among the inradii of these triangles. $\triangle DEF$ is the tricky one, but it's not hard to see that the angle bisectors of $\triangle DEF$ meet the sides of $\triangle ABC$ at right angles: therefore, the incenter of $\triangle DEF$ is actually the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$. This provides a fairly uncomplicated (if not-necessarily-obvious) path to a formula for the inradius of $\triangle DEF$. The result will then be clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the $\triangle ABC$ is acute. [image]
Few (easy) observations:

1. $H$ is the center of the incircle of $\triangle DEF$ -- $H,E,B,F$ lie on a circle, so $\angle HDF=\angle HBF=90^\circ - A$. Similarly, $\angle HDE=\angle HCE=90^\circ-A$.
2. $\triangle BDF$ is similar to $\triangle BAC$ -- $BD:AB=BF:BC=\cos B : 1$.
3. $BH$ is the diameter of the circumcircle of $\triangle BDF$ -- $\angle HFB=\angle HDB = 90^\circ$.

Now $\rho_2:r = BD:AB$, so $\rho_2=r\cos B$. Thus we have
$$\rho_1\rho_2\rho_3 = r^3\cos A\cos B\cos C.$$
So we need to show that
$$\rho = 2R\cos A\cos B\cos C.\tag{1}$$
Let $G $ be the foot of the perpendicular from $H $ on $DE $.
Since $$\rho=HG=HD\sin(\angle HDE)=HD\sin(90^\circ-A)=HD\cos A,$$
and
$$HD=BH\sin(\angle HBD)=BH\sin(90^\circ -C) = BH\cos C,$$
Equality (1) becomes
$$BH\cos A\cos C=2R\cos A\cos B\cos C$$
which is equivalent to
$$BH=2R\cos B.\tag{2}$$
But from Observation 2 and 3 we have
$$BH:2R = BD:AB =\cos B:1.$$
Thus Equality (2) holds. QED

Comment: I did not understand how $H$ is the incenter of triangle $DEF$,why $BDF$ is similar to $BAC$,why BH is diameter of the circumcircle of $BDF$?@Quang Hoang.It may be easy but not clicking to me.

Comment: @diya See the explanations after the statements.

Answer (score 2):

Since the geometical calculus is rather bulky, the sheet below includes only the main equations :

[image]

[image]

In order to save space and time, the known formulas of radii are not repeated here. References :

$[1]$ : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumradius.html   Equation (1)

$[2]$ : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incircle.html   Equation (7)

Thanks very much to have pointed out some typos in the attached sheet. They are corrected.